# Small software inaccuracy may induce cascade of unfounded complaints - should I acknowledge the situation and communicate it back?

Tags: software-development, complaint, customer-service, customer-relation

As a software developer I have observed that small software inaccuracy/inaccuracies (bug, but small and quite hard to define and understand from the user point of view) (that may sometimes happen) may degrade the end-user morale, may relax their attitudes and induce loss of concentration and as a result they may perceive the software as less good than previously thought and as a result they may "find" and report further unfounded problems that are just misunderstandings due to the loss of their attitudes and concentration.

I acknowledge such situations for myself and I try to manage and label such complaints accordingly for myself. But should I acknowledge and communicate this situation to my customers and indiciate somehow as such? I guess that humor can help in this situation, but I am bad at it and it my be unprofessional either. Just perceiving such stream of issues with the full gravity of the real problems is not the solution either.

Comment: _"bug, but small and quite hard to define and understand from the user point of view"_ Those should usually be sold as _'feature'_ to your users/customers.. ;) On a serious note: As a software-developer, are you in the position (is it one of your responsibilities) to communicate directly with your comanies customers in such a matter?

Comment: "Humor" is quite overrated. Humor goes down especially badly if the user is annoyed. Humor is fine if I, as a customer, find a funny misspelling in some alert and tell you. Humor is absolutely inappropriate if I, as a customer, just wasted ten minutes of my valuable time because of a stupid misbehaviour of your software.

Comment: Are you sole developer on this project or part of a team? There sounds like a magnitude of things aren't working right including testing, releasing, and capturing these bugs.

Answer (score 7):

> may degrade the end-user morale

> may relax their attitudes and induce loss of concentration

> may perceive the software as less good

> may "find" and report further unfounded problems

Your post is hyper-focused on how customers "may" react to a bug. Have any customers actually reported issues with a specific bug?

If there is genuinely a bug, I'd expect your team to have some process to document, prioritize (this is where customer reports / impact would become most important), and resolve appropriately. If there isn't a process already, you should create one.

How you communicate to your customers is likely proportional to the severity of the bug -- if it's urgent then you may need to send a special communication alongside the fix. If it's a minor bug, perhaps there's a normal release schedule that it can be rolled into and documented there. It's tough to say without knowing the severity / impact of the issue (and if any customers have already complained).

Comment: Good point asking if any customers have actually already filed a complaint- it's a bit unclear from what the OP describes (due to the _may_'s).. _" I'd expect your team to have some process"_ - normally some ticket-system such as Jira, Atera, D365, etc. - even Gitlab has an 'Issues'-tool..

Comment: There are certain bugs where customers don't file a complaint - if the software is unnecessarily hard to use, or provokes user errors through its design, they may blame themselves instead of complaining. If they hate the software, they don't complain to you. On the other hand, if they think your software is 99% perfect, they'll complain about the 1% _to help you_ getting it closer to 100%. No complaints can be a very bad sign.

Answer (score 4):

If your software behaves as designed, and behaving as designed leaves the end user unhappy and possibly hating your software, then you have a bug. It's a bug in the design of your software, and you need to fix it. As a developer and not designer, you can say "it's not my bug", but it's still your responsibility to do what you can to make someone change the design, and then of course you implement the design change.

If your software behaves as designed, and behaving as designed leads to calls to your customer support, then that behaviour is not only a bug, it is a bug that costs your company money directly. Again, that needs fixing.

Whether you acknowledge a problem to the customer, that may be more up to support / marketing / sales people who have more experience than you how to talk to customers in a way that keeps them happy, and doesn't give them ammunition to sue your company. Imagine your company has a contract saying "all acknowledged bugs need to be fixed within one month", and you don't know about that contract, and you acknowledge a bug without telling anyone and without fixing it. That can be trouble.